# css multiple classes - the propper separator

Tags: css

Everywhere on web I found that multiple css classes use a space as separator.
So, I'm write the following:

```
<div class="page hidden">
```

css

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Using the above code `.hidden` IS NOT hidden, but visible.

But using:

```
<div class="page, hidden">
```

`.hidden` IS hidden.

Any explanation !?

Comment: The space is the proper delimiter and works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r1us08a3/. Are you sure you don't have other CSS rules that might be causing an issue? Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: mm maybe the .page has an important declaration overriding .hidden?

Comment: try to put `!important` and see if you override any other declaration.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/r1us08a3/1/ from @j08691 fiddles'

Comment: `.page{ display:block!important}` this is the problem. Try to remove the `!important` from the `.page` and use it for the `.hidden`.

Comment: @user1012181 where do you see this implementation?

Comment: @NicoO: In the jsFiddle @ AwRak provided.

Comment: Well it is just a guess, I am not sure if the OP meant this...

Comment: @bonaca, please try this and let us know.

Comment: @user1012181 i think this was just a demonstration and not the actual code from the op.

Comment: @NicoO: Yes, I just used the same to demonstrate the solution :)

Comment: Moreover, by placing a comma between your classes, like in `class="page, hidden"`, you're essentially removing the page class from being applied, which leads me to believe something in the page class (or other CSS you may have) is causing the problem, but you didn't post what's in your page class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were doing everything correct. The only explanation is that you have something else affecting it that you haven't put in your question.

Just to prove it works:

```css
div {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:150px;
  line-height:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
div div {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  border-radius:75px;
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:75px;
  line-height:150px;
}
.green {
  background-color:green;  
}
.red {
  background-color:red;  
  color:white;
}
.hidden {
  display:none;  
}
.visible:hover .hidden {
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<div class="green visible">
  <div class="red hidden">
    hidden div
  </div> 
  hover here
</div>
```

Comment: The "you have something else affecting it" suggestions have been floated in the comments above multiple times. Not much of an answer.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, but comments don't prove it. Based upon all the information available in it's current form, this is what I deemed as an answer.

Comment: The only thing that would prove anything is if the OP posted a complete code example, which he failed to do. Until then, all any of us are doing is speculating.

Answer (score 3):

Just for example:

```
.page{ display:block}

.hidden{
    display:none!important;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1us08a3/2/

Comment: The OP does not state anywhere that they are using this (currently).

Comment: I'm just using it for an example.

Comment: :) Even I was curious about the problem. Just wanted him to try this and let us know if it still has problem.

Answer (score 2):

the stacking order of your css will effect the styles that are applied. Also the specificity of the tags used will effect what you see from the front end.
so as an example:

```css
/* .hidden is ignored  in this example because .page comes after the hidden tag */
.hidden {display:none;}
.page {display: block;}


/* where as this will hold as it's more specific to the page, so will take a higher priority */
body .hidden{display: none;}
/* or this as it's more specific to the exact tags above */
.page.hidden {display: none;}
```